# Publish as Azure WebJob not working in VS 2013

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to publish a Azure website along with some azure webjobs using Visual Studio 2013. I'm following [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/).

My solution has the following structure:

[image: Solution Explorer]

When I try to add an existing project as a webjob to my Web project I get a blank dropdown in the Project Name options and I can't:

[image: Add azure webjob]

If I try to add each webjob individually I also have an error:
[image]

In [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/886bbc36-f10d-4233-bd44-f3c8ecab71ce/new-publish-as-azure-webjob-feature-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) it looks like they had a similar problem and the issue due to the fact that the webjobs are under a solution folder. There's no answer/solution to the problem in that thread though.

I was wondering if there's a solution/workaround to this since I don't want to get rid of the solution folders in my project to keep it organized and deploying the webjobs manually is really tedious.

**Update:**
Here's a screenshot of a new project and the Add Azure Webjob doesn't work with Solution Folders.

[image: new webjob]

Comment: It works for me even with solution folder. I'm using VS 2013 Express for Web. Did you try to recreate the solution? Does it work for fresh projects? What edition of VS do you use?

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 ultimate. This solution was firts built with VS 2012 Ultimate and now I'm using VS2013 because I want to take advantage of the webjobs deployment feature. If you look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/886bbc36-f10d-4233-bd44-f3c8ecab71ce/new-publish-as-azure-webjob-feature-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview you'll see that this is an issue. I couldn't fins a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Expand Properties in the solution explorer... and make sure you have a file called "webjob-publish-settings" with the json content:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "[put the name of your webjob here]",
  "startTime": null,
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": null,
  "interval": null,
  "runMode": "Continuous"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, all of my 'webjob-publish-settings.json' files are correctly set up. When I move the webjobs out of the Solution Folders, everything works fine.

Comment: hmm.. i had the same problem. Then I manually copied webjob-publish-settings.json and the profiles under Properties/PublishProfiles from another working Job, and it solved the problem. You may be facing something else...

Answer (score 0):

Installing azure sdk2.5 or above should solve this problem:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Comment: Been running on Azure SDK 2.5 for a while now. Problem still exists.

Comment: Can you try creating a new web application, create a couple of console applications inside solution folders and see if you can see the list when you right click the wap -> Add -> Existing project as Azue webjob. Would like to confirm if the issue is specific to projects created using VS2012.