# Relevant dependencies (DLL) not being copied when deploying using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

In one of the webjobs I'm deploying, I'm referencing one of my class libraries (Core) that is taking care of running some process (in this case sending an email using SendGrid).

When I deployed my webjobs manually (uploading .zip file) everything worked fine. I cleaned up the deployment and re-deployed using Visual Studio 2013 and the webjob started to have problems. The main issue here is that it's looking for the SendGrid dll that's referenced by my Core class library and not my Console app and it's not finiding it throwing the following error:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid.... Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I FTP'd into the website and found that effectively the SendGrid assembly is not where my WebJob is at.

My question is: is there a way to force that this dependencies get copied to the right directory when deploying using VS 2013?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a member of the team who put the WebJobs tooling out in the Summer 2013 Update, and I can let you know we're aware of this issue and have checked in a fix for it for the next update, which is coming out soon. In the meantime, the workaround is to set **assembly references to the assemblies you need - *the NuGet packages alone will do solve this issue* - and re-publish**. We actually use a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish/) to do our deployment logic for WebJobs within VS. Once we release the update, we'll also release the NuGet (which is going through final testing now), so customers on the Summer *and* Fall updates will have this issue mitigated.

Comment: Thanks for the info Brady. Is there any specific place in which I can report issues? I had the problem of solution folders not working (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810050/publish-as-azure-webjob-not-working-in-vs-2013) and also, when I deploy to a website, I have to manually add the AzureJobsDashboard connection string in Azure rather than put them in my solution's connection string and publish it. Thanks again.

Comment: We have a few different forums you can use and we also have our MS Connect tools online, which allow you to file issues with us. Connect is about the best way, as we get customer issues funneled right to the appropriate teams.

Comment: Thank you, I will file the issues I found through the suggested tool.

Comment: @bradygaster Is there anything special about nuget packages in this scenario or can I just add boring old regular assembly references (with copy local = true)?

Comment: @bradygaster does RC 1.0 solve this issue? I just tried it and it didn't work for me that's why I'm asking. But I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Will this solve the same issue if other files are needed in the output folder, like Razor views for Postal?

Comment: Any news on when this "next update" will be available? I am experiencing the same issue with a current WebJob deployment.

Comment: I've got a problem during publish that "The target "ResolveWebJobFiles" does not exist in the project" and another one about the version conflict on Microsoft.Azure.Storage.dll getting from NuGet. Your answer just reminder me that I've deleted Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish. Fixed by re-install the Publish package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is a known bug from [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652785/visual-studio-does-not-copy-referenced-assemblies-through-the-reference-hierarchy) and unfortunately they dont seem too eager to fix it. Possible solutions:

1. You can either manually copy it over
2. Create a build event to copy it over
3. Seems some people have had luck adding something like this 
   `var t = typeof(ThirdParty.SomeClass);`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by doing the following.

1. Set your referenced assemblies "Copy Local -> True"
2. Set your solution configurations to "Release"