# Publish Azure WebJob including all items from bin-folder

Tags: azure, deployment, publish, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to publish my WebJob which is connected to an Azure Website. So I use Publish on the website. This will publish the site and inside the App_Data-Folder the files for the WebJob are deployed.

The problem is, that I use the NuGet package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types inside the WebJob which brings 2 dlls one of which is a C++ native lib. This dll lays in "/bin/SqlServerTypes" of my WebJob-bin-folder which wouldn't be deployed by the publish-operation. Only items directly laying inside of the bin-Folder of the WebJob are deployed.

How can I ensure, that the complete bin-folder from the WebJob-project is deployed to App_Data on the web?

What I tried so far is:

- Adding a project-reference to the WebJob-project in the WebSite-project.
- Generating the folder-structure under App_Data in VS and referencing the dll there.

**Edit:** Turns out, that I had a simple spelling bug when creating the structure beneath the App_Data-Folder. In my case it worked when I just added those dlls in the folder the tooling expected them to be. See the answers for other good links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. [Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859089/relevant-dependencies-dll-not-being-copied-when-deploying-using-visual-studio)

As far as I know, this hasn't been solved yet. A workaround is to copy the relevant dependencies via FTP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is similar. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: FTP is no solution for me but I'll mark your answer as the solution since it points out the main thing.

Comment: @sprinter252 Glad you worked it out. I'll try out your solution for my deployment.