# Deploying a WebJob with a static Content file

Tags: azure-webjobs

A WebJob running on Azure does not seem to drop the <Content> files (Copy if Newer) into the correct directory.

I get the following error:

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\LongTasks\lprysn1r.tsv\Content\File.cshtml`

And I try to access that file as such:
`File.ReadAllText("Content/File.cshtml");`

When running locally, it works just fine.

Is there a way to get this static file dropped appropriately?

Comment: You can check if the file is present when you deploy via FTP. Also, keep in mind that you can only read from the webjob´s folder, you won´t be able to write to that location.

Comment: @lopezbertoni I tried that but it didn't seem to be deployed somewhere I can access? It seems to be on local/Temp

Comment: You can get the FTP credentials from the publish profile. The webjob is deployed to the app_data folder within the web app folder structure. If the file is not correctly deployed, you can always copy it manually via FTP. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495492/publish-azure-webjob-including-all-items-from-bin-folder/27504190#27504190

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some tests, the convention is they do a shallow copy of the /bin/Release folder to App_Data/jobs/continuous/LongTasks/

Which means, if there are any folders, they are not being copied.
Moving the "File.cshtml" to the root directory fixes this problem.

I know this is not fully related to the Azure WebJobs SDK, but this is happening on 6/22/2015 with version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **WEBJOBS_PATH** environment variable for currently running webjob.

```
var webjobPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_PATH");

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(webjobPath))
{
   // Handle dev environment
   webjobPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
```

This will return some path like D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\\xxeeeexxx.qzx\, which contains your content files and folders.