# asp.net not deploying non-referenced assemblies

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

I have a asp.net mvc project that is part of a azure cloud project. Lets call it `WebRole`.

The `WebRole` project depends on a service interface witch is in it's own assembly. Let's call that `Services`. The implementation of those service interfaces sits in yet another assembly, which we can call `Services.Implementations`.

The `WebRole` project have no direct dependency on `Service.Implementations`, but the IoC-container will map things together. The problem is that as long as the direct reference is not there, `Service.Implementations` won't get deployed. Neither to local IIS Express or to the cloud.

How can I tell that the `Service.Implementations` project needs to be deployed, without exposing it to the `WebRole` project?

Comment: That's a known issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859089/relevant-dependencies-dll-not-being-copied-when-deploying-using-visual-studio

Comment: A known issue that should have been fixed already as the look of it ('we have checked in a fix..' one year ago). It's not 100% match, though. It looks like it has to do with nuget packages, but this is local projects in the same solution...

Answer (score 0):

Whole dependency chain will be deployed always. So if you code *might* load the Services.Implementation assembly (because of instantiating a class, interface, whatever from that), it will be deployed. 
So deploying this dll means that your code might use this assembly. If you dont want it, check your classes regaring interface implementations, inheritances, namespaces and using-s.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I **want** it to be deployed. I *know* it will be loaded. But it fails, cause it's not there, because 'the whole dependency chain' isn't deployed. Probably because VS doesn't understand the dependency chain since part of it is dynamic...