# Azure WebJob not working in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure-webjobs

I'm using VS 2015 Community with Update 2 and recently I have got a strange problem where Azure WebJob dialog won't appear.

I have an existing ASP.NET Web Application Project and want to add a new WebJob project to it, but I can't get any dialog or logs when I right-click the project and click "Add" -> "New Azure WebJob Project" or "Existing Project as Azure Webjob". Just the second screenshot in [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/) I want to see.

I have already installed Azure SDK 2.9.1 and Nuget Packages related to WebJob such as "Microsoft.Web.WebJobs. Also I tried to run VS as an Administrator according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810050/publish-as-azure-webjob-not-working-in-vs-2013), do the same command on my laptop, repair the SDK and deploy a standalone WebJob by creating a new project from scratch.

Yet the situation isn't changed so far. Is there still something necessary which I have not come up with?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see in that context menu?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today ( only difference is , i user VS 2015 enterprise update 2). So installed the Azure Tools for VS 2015 again and it got resolved , i can see publish as azure web job option now.  Below is the link from where i downloaded the azure tools

https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/VWDOrVs2015AzurePack.appids